# Ktor Netty Server sending an empty response

Tags: kotlin, netty, ktor

I'm using ktor 0.9.5. I'm trying a simple example. But when a try to connect to the server i get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. This is my code.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "localhost") {
        install(DefaultHeaders)
        install(CallLogging)
        routing {
            get(path = "/") {
                call.respondText("Hello World!!")
            }

        }
    }.start()
}
```

Doing some research I found that changing the project to Maven fix the problem, but because of rules of my organization I can't do it. Any other solution... Thanks before hand.

I have added a `println("sometext")` before `call.respondText("Hello World!!")` and it's never executed.

Comment: "changing the project to Maven" - meaning you are currently using gradle? The code you posted works fine for me using gradle. also can you show us the http request you are making?

Comment: Actually i CAN´T use any dependecy tools not even gradle. My company proxy don´t let me go trough the repos. I download every single dependency myself (really hard work) y don´t think I´m missing any depdency because there´s not a ClassNotFound Exception on the server startup.

Comment: There´s any way to download the dependecy list with out actually download it. So I can check one by one what I need and what I have.

Answer (score 0):

With **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** error, I  guess you are requesting the server from a Google Chrome browser. Right ?
Are you trying to connect to the server from another computer? If so it won't work because you have set the server to only respond for requests coming from localhost.

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "localhost")
```

Even if you add a println() it won't execute.
Try to remove **host = "localhost"** from embeddedServer() parameters an re-test.

Comment: You are rigth I am using Google Chrome, but my url request is http://127.0.0.1:8080/. So it's local.

Comment: By th way a try to remove localhost, it´'s still use 127.0.0.1 by default so same issue.

Comment: @DarioDeyaDiaz did you ever fix this? I got the same trouble [I asked the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412555/ktor-netty-server-is-returning-empty-response)