# Ktor Netty Server is returning empty response

Tags: java, netty, ktor

The below snippet is taken from the [quick start](https://ktor.io/quickstart/index.html) on the Ktor website.

```
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        get("/") {
             call.respondText("Hello World!", ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }
        get("/demo") {
             call.respondText("HELLO WORLD!")
        }
}
server.start(wait = true)
```

My console output looks like this

```
[07:32:13.144 INFO ] application          | No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
[07:32:13.308 INFO ] application          | Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652549/ktor-netty-server-sending-an-empty-response) and tried adding `host = localhost` but this did not fix my issue. I am accessing the link `http://127.0.0.1:8080/demo` like the quick start page directs but am getting `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I have also tried to send a `curl -i http://127.0.0.1/demo` request from the same machine but receive `(52) Empty reply from server`.

Comment: try to change your port something else than 8080 try 8181

Comment: Tried 1234 before, had same error thanks for replying though @Sabeeh

Comment: Changing port for me worked, 8080 to 8081
Maybe some port issue, I was getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE