# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for Specific Localhost Path

Tags: java, google-chrome, safari, httpserver

I created a local HttpServer with a context to handle redirects during the OAuth authorization process. During the redirect process, the server receives key-value pairs in the URL, which I parse and store in queryPairs. If queryPairs is not empty, I display one of two HTML files. If queryPairs is empty, then I attempt to display the "HTML/NoQueries.html" file. However, when I launch my application and search "http://localhost:80/Authorization" (and expect the HTML/NoQueries.html file to display), Safari displays that it "can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection". Chrome sends a "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error message specifying that "localhost didn't send any data".

I have verified that all HTML files are functional. I have confirmed that "http://localhost:80/Authorization?paramA=valueA" and "http://localhost:80/Authorization?paramB=valueB" is functional. I have also confirmed that when `!state.equals(queryPairs.get("state"))` a response code is received. I have looked at [this question] ([Ktor Netty Server is returning empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412555/ktor-netty-server-is-returning-empty-response)).

How should I resolve the error message and display the HTML/NoQueries.html file?

Thank you for your help!

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 0);
server.createContext("/Authorization", new AuthorizationHandler());
server.setExecutor(null);
server.start();

static class AuthorizationHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        if (exchange.getRequestMethod().equals("GET")) {
            String[] pairs = exchange.getRequestURI().getQuery().split("&");
            for (String pair : pairs) {
                int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
                final String key = idx > 0 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : pair;
                final String value = idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : null;
                queryPairs.put(key, value);
            }
            if (queryPairs.size() != 0) {
                if (state.equals(queryPairs.get("state"))) {
                    if (queryPairs.containsKey("paramA")) {
                        File file = new File("HTML/FileA.html");
                        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
                        try (OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody()) {
                            Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
                        }
                        try {
                            methodA();
                            methodB();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (queryPairs.containsKey("paramB")) {
                        File file = new File("HTML/FileB.html");
                        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
                        try (OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody()) {
                            Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(403, -1);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Queries");
                File file = new File("HTML/NoQueries.html");
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
                try (OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody()) {
                    Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
                }
            }
        } else {
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(501, -1);
        }
    }
}
```